# Getting first and last element of array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Mongo DB: I'm looking to make one query to return both the first and last element of an array. I realize that I can do this multiple queries, but I would really like to do it with one.

Assume a collection "test" where each objects has an array "arr" of numbers:

```
 db.test.find({},{arr:{$slice: -1},arr:{$slice: 1}});
```

This will result in the following:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"), "arr" : [ 1 ] }    <-- 1 is the first element
```

Is there a way to maybe alias the results? Similar to what the mysql `AS` keyword would allow in a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment but will be with the Aggregation Framework that's in development now if I understand your functional requirement correctly.

You have to wonder about your schema if you have this requirement in the first place though. Are you sure there isn't a more elegant way to get this to work by changing your schema accordingly?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually in the process of developing my schema for a project, focusing on making my db calls as efficient as possible. For now, I can compromise by keeping my array sizes smaller and passing the entire thing back and fourth. The other side of this problem is not being able to push and pop in a single update. Arrays are a natural container for queues and being able to maintain them through efficient database queries would be yet another excellent benefit to using mongo.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the aggregation framework using the operators [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) and [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/) as follows:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'firstElem': { '$first': '$arr' },
        'lastElem': { '$last': '$arr' }
    } }
])
```

or using [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) as

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'firstElem': { '$slice': [ '$arr', 1 ] },
        'lastElem': { '$slice': [ '$arr', -1 ] }
    } }
])
```