# Get 1st & last item from array of unknown length - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have documents in a collection. Each document may or may not have a `log` field. If it does, this `log` field will be an array. This array is of **unknown** length. I've been trying to use the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator here as best I can & I have gotten it to return the last item in the array with `log: { $slice: -1 }` or the 1st item in the array with `log: { $slice: 1 }` but I cannot figure out how to get both from a **single** db find query. My query to the db is this:

```js
db.collection('entities').find({}, {
    name: 1,
    log: {
        $slice: -1 // returning the last item
    }
})
```

Is this possible with a simple find query or will I have to use an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) query?

I did attempt something like:

```js
db.collection('entities').find({}, {
    name: 1,
    "log.0": 1,
    log: {
        $slice: -1
    }
})
```

But this failed due to a conflict with `$slice` apparently but I imagine it would fail anyway as the `log` field may or may not exist.

Comment: Try the [Array Expression Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators) `$first` and `$last`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168224/getting-first-and-last-element-of-array-in-mongodb